# Infinite loop in redux-saga with multiple puts

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I have a watcher function listening to an action.
Why does this give me an infinite loop?

```
export function* watchFetchBookRequest() {
  yield takeLatest(FETCH_BOOK_REQUEST, handleFetchBookRequest)
}

export function* handleFetchBookRequest(action) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(axios.get, "http://myapicall.com")
    yield put({type: LOADING_START})
    yield put({type: FETCH_BOOK_SUCCESS, payload: response.data})
    yield put({type: LOADING_STOP})
  } catch (error) {
    yield put({type: FETCH_BOOK_FAILURE})
  }
}
```

What is curious is that if I remove `yield put({type: LOADING_START})` the loop is gone.

Comment: Could you post code where your actions are being defined as well as your other reducers? Perhaps `LOADING_START` is somehow dispatching a `FETCH_BOOK_REQUEST`?


Also you'd probably want `LOADING_START` to be dispatched before making the API call. As you have it now it won't "start loading" until after the API call completes

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what the problem was. I had a parent component that was displaying a loading element if the state.isLoader was true, else it would render the component that dispatches `FETCH_BOOK_REQUEST` on `componentWillMount()`.

So on dispatch of `FETCH_BOOK_REQUEST`, the loader is set to true, `FETCH_BOOK_SUCCESS` will be called and the loader is set to false. By doing so it triggered again `componentWillMount()`, ...